# how to console log data observable to string in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, console, angular11

i have case like this :

```
ngOnInit(): void {


this.catalogService.listSearch(this.keywordSearch).subscribe(x => {
  console.log('akhir keyword ==', x.find());
  // console.log('ini lenght ==', x.length);
  if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    this.top5cust = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this.enterpriseProds = x.map(x => {
      return {
        group : x.group,
        id : x.id,
        name : x.name,
        product_id: x.product_id,
        product_name: x.product_name
      };
    });
  }
});

this.combSub.route = this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe( params => {
  console.log('ini masuk search == ', params);
  this.keywordSearch = params;
  console.log('output search == ', this.keywordSearch);
});

let a;
a = this.catalogService.listSearch(this.keywordSearch);
console.log('a coba == ', a);
};
```

I try to console.log the `this.keywordSearch` data in `catalogService.listSearch` and the data type is of type `Observable`. How can I get the value for `this.keywordSearch`. I use this for Searching in API

Comment: Can you share the whole console.log that got return from the code? Just to see which actually got return from all the `log` you have made.

Comment: From what I can see, probably the log `'a coba == '` will return `a coba == undefined` If this is the case then the problem is with the definition of `a`

Comment: was able to successfully display the console value @BelleZaid Thank you for your help